# Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I checked previous answers for this type of error but most of them regard mapping and I am not sure what I should return in this case. My error says that *CorrectDataHandler' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.*

My type and component look as follows:

TYPES:

```
// ERRORS TYPE
interface SourceType {
  pointer: string;
}
interface ErrorsType {
  details: string[];
  source: SourceType;
  title: string;
}

// DATA TYPE
export interface DataType {
  content?: string;
  filename: string;
  format: string;
  batch_id?: number;
}
// META TYPE
interface CountryCurrencyType {
  iso: string;
  name: string;
}

interface MetaType {
  country: CountryCurrencyType;
  currency: CountryCurrencyType;
  local_instrument: string;
  payout_requests?: number;
}

// DATA RESPONSE
export interface DataResponse {
  data: DataType;
  meta?: MetaType;
  errors?: ErrorsType;
}

// RESPONSE
export interface Response {
  status?: number;
  data: DataResponse;
}
```

COMPONENT:

```
{!backToUpload && data && ('data' || 'meta') in data && (
              <div className="rounded-b-lg bg-white py-10 px-6">
                {console.log(data)}
                <CorrectDataHandler data={data as DataResponse} />
                <button
                  className="inpay-button mt-10 w-full"
                  onClick={() => navigateToPayoutBatches(data.data.batch_id)}
                >
                  View batch
                </button>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="inpay-button mt-4 w-full"
                  onClick={() => {
                    setBackToUpload(true);
                    resetForm();
                  }}
                >
                  Upload another batch
                </button>
              </div>
            )}
```

The component I render looks like this:

```
    import { DataResponse } from '.';

interface DataProps {
  data: DataResponse;
}
const CorrectDataHandler = ({ data }: DataProps) => {
  if (data.data && data.meta) {
    return (
      data && (
        <div>
          <div>
            Format: <span className="font-semibold">CSV</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            Name: <span className="font-semibold">{data.data.filename}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            Type:{' '}
            <span className="font-semibold">{data.meta.local_instrument}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            Corridor:
            <span className="ml-1 font-semibold">
              {data.meta.currency.iso} ({data.meta.currency.name}) -{' '}
              {data.meta.country.iso} ({data.meta.country.name})
            </span>
          </div>
          <div>
            Total: <span>{data.meta.payout_requests}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly return `null` since `undefined` is not a valid JSX Element:-

```
const CorrectDataHandler = ({ data }: DataProps) => {
  if (data.data && data.meta) {
    //...
  }
  return null; // <-- add this return
};
```

---

The error message is trying to tell you that your component returns `undefined` *sometimes*, and hence cannot be rendered without fixing it.

In your specific case `CorrectDataHandler` will return undefined when `if (data.data && data.meta)` condition is not met.

In JS, an implicit `undefined` is returned from functions, if there isn't one explicitly provided.

```js
// this code
function f1() {
  if (condition) {
    return 'foo';
  }
}

// is equivalent to
function f1() {
  if (condition) {
    return 'foo';
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rheaditi, but then what is the point of making a condition to render the component or not, If the condition in the parent returns null then the component will be not displayed. Then returning null in the child wouldn't be useless? if correct, does it mean that the condition in the parent component is not covering correctly the child rendering? if yes what condition should I put in the parent component in order to avoid this return null in the child? I have another component where I never returned null and it works:/

Comment: Typescript checking that a component always returns a valid JSX Element is independent of the different conditionals you use in the parent or the child.

In order to be valid "Component", `CorrectDataHandler` must return either React nodes or null. Only valid components can be rendered. 

This ensures that this component can be rendered inside any parent component, regardless of the logic in the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Add a default condition when `if` fails

```
 if (data.data && data.meta) {
   return (
     ....
   )
  }

  return null
```

Comment: try returning `<> </>`